# what is the correct version of Eclipse for Coldfusion?

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion

Usually when one wants to create a new file in the Eclipse IDE , Java, Javascript, Colsdfusion PHP etc are provided as the options for the new files.

I recently downloaded Eclipse for Coldfusion 8 and excecuted the file "software/dw/java/europa/J2EE-SDK-Europa-33-win32.zip" .

Now when I want to create a  New File "only JAVA " option is available. There is no coldfusion or HTML!

So can any one provide me the Exact/correct link for Codfusion related Eclipse?
(On the Eclipse website there are many Eclipse related downloads but I am not sure which one is specific for Coldfusion.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's also Adobe's [ColdFusion Builder IDE](http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion/cfbuilder/features/) specially created for this purpose. It proposes some features not available in CFEclipse, but not free (though there's a trial version available).

In addition to Ken's answer please note that you can already use preview builds of CFEclipse with latest Eclipse 3.6 Helios. I am using this configuration on daily basis and it is pretty stable and more efficient than previous version for me.

If you will expierience problems with preview builds, feel free to post them into the [CFEclipse groups](http://groups.google.com/group/cfeclipse-users), developers usually react pretty quickly.

One more hint for you. Sometimes after installing the plugin via *Add Sofware* further updates do not work correcly. I've experienced this issue few times so it can be useful to know the solution.

To fix this check the *Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites*. If needed entry missing -- create it manually using the same update URL as for installation.

Also there's an Eclipse-based version of Adobe CF manual available, see this [help page](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/othertechnologies_11.html) for details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks Segii but where to find "Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites"?

Comment: I am getting the error "netwrok connection problems encountered during the search" while trying to add "software updates" to Eclipse "

Comment: Do you have Eclipse installed, right? Look in the Window menu, you'll see the Preferences item there. As for the networking problems, this can be something related to the internet/proxy settings, or you're doing something wrong when adding update site. I've just updated the preview build without problems.

Comment: I have JAVA eclipse SDE .I have looked in "Window > Preferences > Install/Update > "  I do not have "Available Software Sites" rather I ahve "Automatic Updates" which was unchecked and I have checked it now.

Comment: Further I don not have Admin rights on my system so will that cause the error "netwrok connection problems encountered during the search"?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a Windows user so can't say about permissions as possible reason. Can you open the update URL in the browser? I suggest you to edit your question and explain all your steps so we can better understand possible problems.

Answer (score 6):

There's [CFEclipse](http://www.cfeclipse.org/), a free, open-source Eclipse plug-in for working with CFML. And of course there's Adobe's [ColdFusion Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion/cfbuilder/features/), a commercial product that works as either a plug-in for an existing Eclipse installation, or as a full stand-alone product (with Eclipse already baked in).

CFEclipse 1.3.6, the current stable version, works with Eclipse 3.4.x or 3.5.x. Here's the [CFEclipse wiki](http://trac.cfeclipse.org/).

The stated Eclipse versions required for ColdFusion Builder are 3.4.2 or 3.5. Here's [Adobe's requirements page](http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion/cfbuilder/systemreqs/).

If you're using one of these as a plug-in and you don't need a lot of the other Eclipse features, the J2EE version of Eclipse is probably overkill (it's the biggest package). You can try out a more minimal Eclipse install, then update and add plug-ins as you need them. Try the [Eclipse Platform Binary](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5-200906111540/), for example.

Comment: I am getting the error "netwrok connection problems encountered during the search" while trying to add "software updates" to Eclipse